# Phonegap barcode scanner also reads checkdigit(code39)

Tags: cordova, barcode-scanner

I'm using the `CaptureActivity(zxing)` as a library in my application to scan barcodes. I recently started scanning different types of barcodes and have an issue with one type.

When I scan `1224015` it scans it as `1224015F`

Its seems like there's a checkdigit or something similar after the barcode. Is there a way to disable this checkdigit so it doesn't appear in the `window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan result.text` (in the js)?

I can't just remove the last digit since I don't know what kind of barcode that was scanned.

I have no experience with barcode scanning and their types.

I've found out that there's a result format which I will try to use to remove the last letter. I would still like a better solution.